# Can we set the primary and secondary device type or they are predefined by the device?

Tags: android, wifi, android-wifi, wifi-direct, wifip2p

I want to broadcast the app information to other devices and for that  I thought of setting the secondary device type to some unique string and identify it while discovering peers ?Is there any way to set the secondary device type or it is set by the device?

Comment: What is the device type you want to deliver through discovery and how are you currently using it ? Also, are you using UPnP or bonjour there ?

Comment: I wanted to deliver a unique application name such that other devices will be able to see and detect it. I am using DNS-sd( I am using th standard protocol which android apps use for service discovery ).

Answer (score 0):

There is no fields which would be called device type, anyway, if the purpose is to have something that you can identify clearly. Then with Bonjour (Dns-Sd) you could indeed define the Service type with the Service advertisement.

Also with the same service advertisement, you also have instance name variable, which you can set your own content which you could indeed use as additional 'Device type' field.

I have not seen any docs on size limitations for the service type or instance name, but did quick [study on the topic](http://www.drjukka.com/blog/wordpress/?p=131) last week, and it looks that the max size for (Service type + instance name) should not exceed 110 characters, and that instance name should not be longer than 100 characters.

I would not recommend using the Txt records at all, since the size limitation posed with the API are made in a way that, if there is any other services advertised on the device, then you can not be certain whether your record information gets advertised or not.